# Average column value changing on pagination

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I was having some trouble finding why jqGrid was changing the average value for a column whenever I went to a different page and came back.

I'm currently using *jqGrid 5.4.0* and I have tried to update it to a newer version (5.8) thinking it could possibly be a minor bug but the problem is still there.

It took me a while to find out what was the origin of the problem, but still no success on finding a solution since I need to use `datatype: jsonstring`. The way I'm populating my grid is what makes the bug happen. (Check examples below)

[Working code using 'datatype: "local"'](http://jsfiddle.net/mj7yz42g/)

As you will see, the JSON I'm using is the same for both codes, the only thing changing being the `data` becoming `datastr` and the `datatype` changing from `local` to `jsonstring`.

[Bugged version of the code using 'datatype: "jsonstring"](http://jsfiddle.net/2r5yxuew/1/)

You can make the bug happen by going to the next page and back to the previous one and keeping an eye on the **Average** value. It will start to divide the value by the number of rows.

Another bug I just noticed is that jqGrid doesn't sum all values and divide by the number of rows, just gets the first value and divides by the rows everytime. Including the first time the grid initializes, the average value is supposed to be 100 because 100*4/4 = 100 (presuming the number of rows is 4).

Comment: The examples you point are not correct since they use jqGrid version 4.6.0. Can you please correct these so that we can look in to it?

Comment: Will do. Didn't pay attention that the demo I was using as a base had jqGrid version 5.4.0. I will be trying to replicate my code on jsFiddle so that it produces the same error of the application. Interesting enough, now that I have changed the configs on JSFiddle to mirror the configs of my app, it's working as it should (which doesn't make sense, given that the error is still happening in the application). While I try to mirror my configurations, the problem is exactly as it is coded on the examples (AVG is being calculated wrongly.)

Comment: Thank you. This is a bug and we have fixed it. It will be available in the next release. The both ways will return the same result - i.e the calculation will be done for all available rows and then we put the appropriate calculated value.